# Why does Chrome DevTool Network have two same request in angular4 project of aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: angular, rxjs, aspnetboilerplate

I found two same request in chrome devtool network when developing the angular4 project. Below is the code of http request: 
Notes: the code above is generated using nswag.

```
userApplyLimitAsync(): Observable<GetUserApplyLimitOutput> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/AElfApplication/UserApplyLimitAsync";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ = {
        method: "post",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request(url_, options_).flatMap((response_) => {
        return this.processUserApplyLimitAsync(response_);
    }).catch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof Response) {
            try {
                return this.processUserApplyLimitAsync(response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<GetUserApplyLimitOutput>><any>Observable.throw(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<GetUserApplyLimitOutput>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
    });
}

protected processUserApplyLimitAsync(response: Response): Observable<GetUserApplyLimitOutput> {
    const status = response.status;

    let _headers: any = response.headers ? response.headers.toJSON() : {};
    if (status === 200) {
        const _responseText = response.text();
        let result200: any = null;
        let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
        result200 = resultData200 ? GetUserApplyLimitOutput.fromJS(resultData200) : new GetUserApplyLimitOutput();
        return Observable.of(result200);
    } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
        const _responseText = response.text();
        return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
    }
    return Observable.of<GetUserApplyLimitOutput>(<any>null);
}
```

Below is the code of invocation of the function `userApplyLimitAsync()`:

```
this._withdrawService.userApplyLimitAsync()
    .subscribe((result) => {
            this.withdrawActive = result.isSucceed;
        });
```

`userApplyLimitAsync()` is the member of `WithdrawServiceProxy`, and `_withdrawService` is the instance of `WithdrawServiceProxy`.
When I call the `userApplyLimitAsync()`, why does it create two same request?
[Two same requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzVHX.jpg)[The first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHvH5.jpg)[The second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXc9E.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 requests but there is lots of diffrence between them.

1. The first request as you can see is `OPTIONS` request
2. Second one is : `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` (Whichever request you made)

`OPTIONS` request is to check if the SERVER allows request operations i.e. `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` (Whichever 
request you made).

These are defined at server at as
E.x.`'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'`.

If the requested method is not allowed in above context then only `OPTIONS` request is called and will return an error.

Answer (score 2):

Not the same request. Not even the same HTTP verb. You should research HTTP verbs, mainly OPTIONS and POST.

Answer (score 0):

[The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are permitted to read that information using a web browser.

Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.

Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials" (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with requests.